# Pandas df.to_datetime formatting error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame in pandas that has a column with dates in it. I am trying to convert these dates into a timestamp that matches the `df.to_datetime` index of 3 other dataframes so that I can `concat` them.

The dataframe is like so:

```
eth_price.head(n=5)

Out[33]: 
               0        1
0  8/28/17 16:19  344.021
1  8/28/17 16:19  344.021
2  8/28/17 16:24  343.833
3  8/28/17 16:29  343.643
4  8/28/17 16:34  343.632
```

When I try and fix this using `eth_price[0] = pd.to_datetime(eth_price[0])`
I get the following error:

> ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.

How can I fix this? The format of the other date/time indices are as follows:

```
btc_price.head(n=5)

Out[35]: 
                     0           1
0  2017-08-27 22:50:00  4,389.6113
1  2017-08-27 22:51:00  4,389.0850
2  2017-08-27 22:52:00  4,388.8625
3  2017-08-27 22:53:00  4,389.7888
4  2017-08-27 22:56:00  4,389.9138
```

Comment: This works on my machine. Are you running the latest version of pandas? Also, does your column contain any unprintable characters and such?

Comment: You could try passing an explicit format string: `pd.to_datetime(eth_price[0], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')`